# Referência de cadeia de caracteres não foi definida

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em Java no Eclipse, para envio de NFSe para Camaquã. O XML é assinado e enviado, porém retorna esse erro no java:

> "Exception: Referência de cadeia de caracteres não foi definida como uma instância de cadeia de caracteres. Nome do parâmetro: s"

Não faço ideia do que causa esse erro e gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar. Log inteiro do erro conforme debugger:

> AxisFault
>    faultCode: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher}InternalServiceFault
>    faultSubcode: 
>    faultString: Referência de cadeia de caracteres não foi definida como uma instância de cadeia de caracteres.
>   Nome do parâmetro: s
>    faultActor: 
>    faultNode: 
>    faultDetail: 
>       {http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel}ExceptionDetail:Referência de cadeia de caracteres não foi definida como uma instância de cadeia de caracteres.
>   Nome do parâmetro: s   em System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
>      em CTIC.NFSE.Model.Implementadas.XML.WCFWebServices.ValidatorManager.ValidateByXsd(String xmlContent, List`1 listaMensagemRetorno)
>      em CTIC.NFSE.Model.Implementadas.XML.WCFWebServices.ValidatorManager.ValidateLotSimplifyForm(String cpfCnpjTransmitter, String xmlDoLote)
>      em CTIC.Framework.Model.Business.BOWebService.RecepcionarLoteRps(String xmlEnvio)
>      em CTIC.NFSE.WebServices.NFSEServices.RecepcionarLoteRps(String xmlEnvio)
>      em SyncInvokeRecepcionarLoteRps(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      em System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.ArgumentNullException
>   Referência de cadeia de caracteres não foi definida como uma instância de cadeia de caracteres.
>   Nome do parâmetro: s
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
>       at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>       at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
>       at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
>       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
>       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
>       at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>       at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>       at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
>       at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
>       at util.WsClient.enviarXMLIpm(WsClient.java:645)
>       at util.GeracaoXML.generateXMLFilePRONIM(GeracaoXML.java:458)
>       at util.GeracaoXML.generateXMLFile(GeracaoXML.java:100)
>       at telas.TelaSimples.main(TelaSimples.java:408)

Comment: Esse erro definitivamente parece estar vindo do webservice de Camaquã. Como é que você está invocando ele?

Comment: O webservice de Camaquã parece ser feito em .net e ele disparou uma exceção `System.ArgumentNullException` porque a string `s` estava nula, o que é análogo a um `java.lang.NullPointerException` no Java. O que você colocou como sendo esse parâmetro `s`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, Os parâmetros passados são:

>call.setSOAPActionURI("http://tempuri.org/INFSEGeracao/RecepcionarLoteRps");

>call.setTargetEndpointAddress("http://nfseteste.camaqua.rs.gov.br/NFSEWSTESTE/Services.svc?wsdl");

>call.setSOAPActionURI("http://tempuri.org/INFSEGeracao/RecepcionarLoteRps");

>call.setOperationName(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "RecepcionarLoteRps"));

Comment: Não sei o que estaria causando esse problema, já que as demais cidades fazem o envio do mesmo jeito e funcionam normalmente. (Porto Alegre, Esteio, Novo Hamburgo, entre outras).

Comment: Pode ser um problema no webservice deles. Ter uma `System.ArgumentNullException` no .net é o mesmo que ter um `java.lang.NullPointerException` no Java - ou é preguiça de tratar os parâmetros `null`s adequadamente ou é erro de programação.